# Trying to move an uploaded file in sub domain A to sub domain B

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am able to just upload the image in subdomain A but I can't, no matter what I do, upload to B. This is what I have:

```
$move_to = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/pinturas/$timestamp-" . $file;

$move_to_site = $this->config->item('testing_domain_root') . "/assets/pinturas/$timestamp-" . $file;

$outputThis = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nuevaPintura']['tmp_name'], $move_to);

$outputOther = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nuevaPintura']['tmp_name'], $move_to_site);
```

The variable: `$this->config->item('testing_domain_root')`is equivalent to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`(I made it so that it's the same just with the different subdomain).

However, upon checking the value of the `move_uploaded_file` methods, the local one (subdomain A) gives me TRUE, while subdomain B returns nothing.

Both subdomains exist within the same server, so I'm lost as to why this could be happening.

Comment: As server is same why you need to upload to other domain ?, can't you save it at a location from where both A and B can access ?

Comment: same server but the fact that it's a different subdomain separates where the images are stored.

Comment: display_error enabled on your sever ? (any specific error you are getting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move_uploaded_file() function moves the source file to another location. You just can't move the same file twice.

As an alternative solution, you can copy the moved file to the second location.

```
$outputOther = copy($move_to, $move_to_site);
```